# Django dynamically modifying querysets

Tags: python, django, rest, pagination

I've got a Django 2.2.28 application running on Python 3.7.7 and I'm trying to add what I think is an unusual query filter. One of the displays is generated by a queryset that is filtered in the normal way against a PostgreSQL database. This data is presented in using a paginator.
I'm being asked to add a filter the data on the display by an additional filter using data that comes from a REST API call (not the database). A simplified presentation to explain what's desired, let's say I have a display with 2 columns, Id and Name that comes from the database:

```
Id Name
1  George
2  Anne
3  Susan
4  Mark
```

The add ask is to add a 3rd column for Status, which comes from a REST API by passing a list of Id values. Adding the Status to the above display would theoretically present this if the list of Ids were passed to the REST API:

```
Id Name     Status
1  George   True
2  Anne     False
3  Susan    True
4  Mark     False
```

The users would like to filter the display based on the Status (True/False) and still have a full page of results (4). The problem is if the user filters for only Status == True, I want to filter out Id 2 and 3. But that makes the display only have 2 results. I need to have this:

```
Id Name     Status
1  George   True
3  Susan    True
6  Helen    True
10 Ben      True
```

To create this display I have to make additional REST API calls with lists of additional Ids till I can fill out the display with 4 results. This means looking forward for Id values till I get enough results to populate the display. I also need to keep the pagination (at least  ...  links)

Any ideas, suggestions, etc would be very welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Are you using django ORM? You can chain-filter your existing queryset and evaluate it to get the first 4 objects e.g. my_queryset.filter(status=True)[:4]

Comment: We are using the ORM, but I guess I wasn't clear in my question. The status isn't part of the database the ORM has access to. The status data comes from a REST API call that uses the Id values from the ORM to get the status for those records. It's kind of a catch-22 problem: I need the Id's to get the status from the REST API, and I need the status to complete the display.

Comment: Why not just do 2 queries? First one to get the initial set of names. Then call the API with that result. Then run a 2nd query to filter out with the API results.

Comment: The problem is that if the 2nd query filters out items based on the API results, the display page would be "short" by that many items. I need to iteratively build towards a query result that fills a complete display page.